# What is the probability of multiple Gaussian distribution measurements to be in agreement.

Tags: gaussian

I have N measurements, each reports a Gaussian distribution of the scalar value (i.e. each reports mean and variance of it: $(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$).

What is the probability that these measurements are "correct"? Or, to phrase it differently, what is the probability that there exists a true value that all the N measurements detected?

This is a practical problem: I have ensemble of N neural networks, they get the same input and output $(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$ each. I want to measure how much they "agree" in a principled way. I.e. if they output exactly the same distribution the agreement should be high, if they output low sigma and means that are far away from each other - the agreement should be low.

Comment: How were the N measurements generated? This sounds like the framework for confidence interval estimation with bootstrapping.

Comment: Are you saying you have $N$ measurements $(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2), \dots, (\mu_N, \sigma_N^2)$ and you want to know some sort of probability they all were obtained from a common distribution? You'd have to specify something about the sampling process. Or maybe you mean something different, such as the confidence you have in each measurement. In that case @AdityaDua has the right idea.

Comment: This is a practical problem: I have ensemble of N neural networks, they get the same input and output $(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$  each.

I want to measure how much they "agree" in a principled way. I.e. if they output exactly the same distribution the agreement should be high, if they output low sigma and means that are far away from each other - the agreement should be low.

Comment: Also clarified by editing the question.